# Jump to first and last slides in Keynote

Tags: keynote

I am on Keynote 11.2

What are the combination of keys to jump to the first and last slides, outside presentation mode, that is, while editing my slides?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Fn + Left Arrow or Home to jump to the first slide and Fn + Right Arrow or End to go to the last slide.

You can find more Keynote keyboard shortcuts on [this Apple Support webpage](https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote/keyboard-shortcuts-tanfde4a3e6d/mac).

Answer (score 1):

First Slide : `Fn-Left Arrow`
Last Slide : `Fn-Right Arrow`

Comment: It seems you answered very shortly after Alper according to sorting the answers from oldest to newest. I voted up your answer because you cared too. Thanks.

Comment: Appreciate it :)